# How to set rDNS record for ipv6 address block?

Tags: ipv6, reverse-dns

Occasionally, I open a ticket at my VPS provider to let them create a rDNS record for me. Sometimes, I can find a page in my control panel to add the rDNS record myself. This is simple for ipv4 address. I just input an ip address and a domain name to create the rDNS record. I wonder how to add rDNS record for a block of ipv6 addresses such as a 2^64 address block. Do I have to add 2^64 rDNS records each mapping an ipv6 address to a domain? Can I have one record to map the whole address block to the same domain?

Comment: Surely you would not be using all the 2^64 addresses? I think the common approach is to add entries as appropriate rather than adding entries for everything whether needed or not. As for having all addresses point to one name, what would be the point (seems like it might be worse than not adding any records at all)?

Comment: I need to rotate the ips to avoid being blocked when sending emails. Smtp servers usually block you if the rdns record is not set. I'm not clear about the exact rdns record format. Does one rdns record only accommodate one ip address?

Comment: "avoid being blocked when sending emails"?? What amounts of mail are you sending? (Also, do you know that one can just as easily block or track reputation for your entire /64? I'd even suspect that's more common than tracking it per-address.)